# I Need Help On regex string

Tags: regex, string, command

I need a string to select everything all html tags text numbers everything, except the random occurrence of words found within the anchor closing tag, of this line `rel="bookmark">RANDOM WORDS</a></h1>`

I tried the string `[<0-9a-zA-z/=|"-:.*?>]` which select's literally everything, it find's that's okay, but I require one that exclude's RANDOM WORDS, in the selection that's found within the line mentioned above.

Comment: It's 2013. Stop using regexes to parse HTML. Use an XML parser.

Comment: The `<center>` cannot hold, it is too late...

Comment: This is a duplicate question. See the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1123744

Comment: possible duplicate of [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Answer (score 1):

Regex's are not the right tool for this job. Please consider using an XML/HTML DOM parser and extract the information you need that way!

The reason you're having trouble with crafting a RegEx to accomplish this task is because the HTML markup language is not *regular* - hence, not suitable for processing with regular expressions!